# SampleDataEvent.data.writeFloat() at at 5kHz, 8kHz,11kHz or 22kHz

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

How many times should I execute SampleDataEvent.data.writeFloat 
when data has been recorded at 5kHz, 8kHz,11kHz or 22kHz ?

The voice has been recorded at 5kHz, 8kHz,11kHz or 22kHz with  flash.media.Microphone.

I refered that 
[SampleDataEvent.data.writeFloat() - Why call it twice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2970140/sampledataevent-data-writefloat-why-call-it-twice)

Answer (score 0):

I've found this page and they describe frequency shifting which may give you some idea about your problem [dynamic audio in as3 part 3](http://philippseifried.com/blog/2011/10/20/dynamic-audio-in-as3-part-3-robot-voice/)